# Infinite products $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos\frac1n$

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

This is my first question.

What are the values of the infinite products $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos\frac1n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1n$?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite product of $\sin(\frac 1 n),\cos(\frac 1 n)$? Elaborate quickly or people will downvote your question,

Comment: Do you mean $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos\frac1n$?

Comment: if n belongs to the Natural numbers, what is the infinite product of cos(1/n)

Comment: Whatever you mean, you need to add some context and show what you've tried. Questions of the type "this is the question, I have no idea" are not well-recieved on this site, and your post may get closed. So please edit your post and add everything that is needed for [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/229831).

Comment: yes mohsen shahriari, i don't know how to use the symbols

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick guide to math formatting.

Comment: Well, $\prod \sin\frac{1}{n}$ is clearly $0$. And while $\prod \cos\frac{1}{n}$ converges, the radian measures $1,1/2,1/3,\cdots$ are quite unnatural, so I wouldn't expect any closed form. Could also ask about $\prod \cos\frac{x}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

For the sines, it is quite simple
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$$ For the cosines the result is just a number
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim0.388536153335175859184329576$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

However, we can approximate it using logarithms since
$$\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{p=1 }^\infty (-1)^p\frac{ 2^{2 p-3} (E_{2 p-1}(1)-E_{2 p-1}(0)) }{p (2 p-1)!\,n^{2 p}}$$ which makes
$$\sum_{n=1 }^\infty \log \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{p=1 }^\infty \frac{(-1)^{p+1} 2^{2 p-3} (E_{2 p-1}(0)-E_{2 p-1}(1)) \zeta (2 p)}{p (2 p-1)!}$$ which converges quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \text{result} \\
 10 & 0.388538882923887752891524656369 \\
 20 & 0.388536153510144960460336253991 \\
 30 & 0.388536153335190159575729146913 \\
 40 & 0.388536153335175860483365339921 \\
 50 & 0.388536153335175859184454814359 \\
 60 & 0.388536153335175859184329588232 \\
 70 & 0.388536153335175859184329575688 \\
 80 & 0.388536153335175859184329575687
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: There is some information about the cosine product at http://oeis.org/A118817

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Thank you for the link. I never think about OEIS for decimal numbers.  Cheers :-)